# How to solve, Error installing packages on 32-bit windows PC

Tags: r, tidyverse, failed-installation

I'm using 32-bit windows PC. Unable to install "tidyverse" packages on to my system. Can someone please help how to install. It's really annoying to see these messages whenever I try to install. Please bare with me, I'm new to the R-world.

```
Version of R:
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)


Below is the comprehensive error:

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
             binary source needs_compilation
memoise       1.1.0  2.0.1             FALSE
fs            1.2.7  1.5.2              TRUE
progress      1.2.0  1.2.2             FALSE
processx      3.3.0  3.7.0              TRUE
highr           0.8    0.9             FALSE
xfun            0.6   0.32             FALSE
htmltools     0.3.6  0.5.3              TRUE
tinytex        0.12   0.41             FALSE
glue          1.3.1  1.6.2              TRUE
blob          1.1.1  1.2.3             FALSE
vctrs         0.1.0  0.4.1              TRUE
tidyselect    0.2.5  1.1.2              TRUE
data.table   1.12.2 1.14.2              TRUE
rematch2      2.0.1  2.1.2             FALSE
ellipsis      0.1.0  0.3.2              TRUE
callr         3.2.0  3.7.2             FALSE
knitr          1.22   1.40             FALSE
rmarkdown      1.12   2.16             FALSE
selectr       0.4-1  0.4-2             FALSE
broom         0.5.2  1.0.1             FALSE
cli           1.1.0  3.3.0             FALSE
dbplyr        1.4.0  2.2.1             FALSE
dplyr       0.8.0.1  1.0.9              TRUE
dtplyr        0.0.3  1.2.2             FALSE
forcats       0.4.0  0.5.2             FALSE
ggplot2       3.1.1  3.3.6             FALSE
googledrive   0.1.3  2.0.0             FALSE
haven         2.1.0  2.5.1              TRUE
hms           0.4.2  1.1.2             FALSE
jsonlite        1.6  1.8.0              TRUE
lubridate     1.7.4  1.8.0              TRUE
magrittr        1.5  2.0.3             FALSE
modelr        0.1.4  0.1.9             FALSE
pillar        1.3.1  1.8.1             FALSE
purrr         0.3.2  0.3.4              TRUE
readr         1.3.1  2.1.2              TRUE
reprex        0.2.1  2.0.2             FALSE
rlang         0.3.4  1.0.4              TRUE
rvest         0.3.3  1.0.3             FALSE
stringr       1.4.0  1.4.1             FALSE
tibble        2.1.1  3.1.8              TRUE
tidyr         0.8.3  1.2.0              TRUE
xml2          1.2.0  1.3.3              TRUE
tidyverse     1.2.1  1.3.2             FALSE

ERROR: dependency 'cachem' is not available for package 'memoise'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/memoise'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/memoise_2.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘memoise’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="xfun.dll" OBJECTS="base64.o init.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/xfun'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/xfun_0.32.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'jquerylib' ...
** package 'jquerylib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'Rcpp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'jquerylib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/jquerylib'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/jquerylib_0.1.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jquerylib’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'blob' ...
** package 'blob' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'blob'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/blob'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/blob_1.2.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘blob’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/lifecycle_1.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'rematch2' ...
** package 'rematch2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rematch2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rematch2'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/rematch2_2.1.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rematch2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.3.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/callr_3.7.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'cli' ...
** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="cli.dll" OBJECTS="ansi.o cleancall.o diff.o errors.o init.o md5.o progress-altrep.o progress.o sha256.o thread.o tty.o utf8.o win-utf8.o winfiles.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cli'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/cli'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/cli_3.3.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'magrittr' ...
** package 'magrittr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="magrittr.dll" OBJECTS="pipe.o utils.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'magrittr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/magrittr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/magrittr_2.0.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'xfun' is not available for package 'highr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/highr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/highr_0.9.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'sass', 'jquerylib', 'cachem', 'memoise' are not available for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/bslib'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/bslib_0.4.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'xfun' is not available for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/tinytex'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/tinytex_0.41.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'cli' is not available for package 'gargle'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/gargle'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/gargle_1.2.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'dtplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dtplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/dtplyr_1.2.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr' are not available for package 'forcats'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/forcats'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/forcats_0.5.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘forcats’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/hms'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/hms_1.1.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'lifecycle' are not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/pillar_1.8.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'magrittr' is not available for package 'stringr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/stringr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/stringr_1.4.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'hms' is not available for package 'progress'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/progress'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/progress_1.2.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘progress’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'highr', 'stringr', 'xfun' are not available for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/knitr_1.40.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'stringr' is not available for package 'selectr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/selectr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/selectr_0.4-2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘selectr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'stringr', 'ggplot2' are not available for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/broom_1.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'blob', 'cli', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'pillar' are not available for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/dbplyr_2.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'gargle', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'pillar' are not available for package 'googledrive'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/googledrive'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/googledrive_2.0.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'bslib', 'jquerylib', 'knitr', 'stringr', 'tinytex', 'xfun' are not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rmarkdown'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_2.16.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'gargle', 'googledrive', 'magrittr', 'rematch2' are not available for package 'googlesheets4'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/googlesheets4'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/googlesheets4_1.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'magrittr' are not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/modelr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/modelr_0.1.9.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'selectr' are not available for package 'rvest'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rvest'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/rvest_1.0.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'callr', 'cli', 'knitr', 'lifecycle', 'rmarkdown' are not available for package 'reprex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/reprex'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/reprex_2.0.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'cli', 'dbplyr', 'dtplyr', 'forcats', 'ggplot2', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'hms', 'magrittr', 'modelr', 'pillar', 'reprex', 'rvest', 'stringr' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/Anwar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/tidyverse'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Anwar\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpANA6pE/downloaded_packages/tidyverse_1.3.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Update R to the latest version, and try again.

Comment: I tried updating, I get msg your using newest version. I believe no update available. OR should I uninstall and then re-install?

Comment: You are using very outdated sofware. You should not be surprised if you fail when you try to combine that with up-to-date software. Update your operating system (to 64bit if possible), update R and then try again. Or install old package versions if you for some reason must use outdated software.

Comment: note that if upgrading R, but not your system to 64-bit, [that R 4.1 is the last version that supported 32-bit versions:](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f)

Comment: "I tried updating, I get msg your using newest version." That doesn't make sense. v3.4.1 is over 5 years old. We're now at 4.2.1 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/

Comment: Okay! @user20650 great and thank you for giving me the lead. I have installed r4.1.3 (32-bit) now and everything seems installed except r graphics but for now that's OK. 
Also thanks for the rest of them who gave their feedback.

Comment: good stuff @AnwarKamdod. What is the problem with the graphics .... it should install fine with the rest of R as it is comes as a binary (all packaged together). Is the issue with graphics in an IDE/GUI say Rstudio?

Comment: @user20650, [current Version Rstudio 1.1.463]. Pls see msg :: Warning message: R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed. ::

Comment: okay, thanks. So I am assuming that plots are produced but they open in a new window rather than the Rstudio plot window.  Your Rstudio version is very old so normally I'd suggest to update. However, I do not know if the newer versions are compatible with 32-bit OS/R.  You could ask at https://community.rstudio.com/ . (I know it doesn't help oyu here but you really do need to make the jump to 64-bit.)

Comment: @user20650, thanks and appreciate for encouraging me. I'll make jump soon to 64-bit, in the mean time I shall do check on this at the community page.